# postgreSQL ADD CONDITION FOR NON EXISTENT VALUES

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, view

I'm creating a new view from several existent tables, with data refreshed daily, I have a select statement like this:

```
SELECT data.hours
data.date_id
data.name
```

obtaining a datatable like this one:

```
NAME   |  DATEID   |   HOURS
Robert |  20200511 |  10      (monday, may 11 2020)
Robert |  20200513 |  8       (wednesday, may 13 2020)
```

the date_id contains the date in CHAR value (ex.20200513) every name should have a value for every day of the week, but sometimes this value will not exist until friday, i want to make a condition where if there is no data for name in some of the past days or today it saves me the hours as '0' instead of not saving any data because it doesn't exist like in this new table.

```
    NAME   |  DATEID   |   HOURS
    Robert |  20200511 |  10      (monday, may 11 2020)
    Robert |  20200512 |  0       (tuesday, may 12 2020)
    Robert |  20200513 |  8       (wednesday, may 13 2020)
```

Comment: So the date value exists in some other table but the corresponding name is not present?

Comment: it just doesn't exist, the only thing I can know for sure is the TIME_ID because i know which date is going to be this week, Robert has no data for tuesday, but i want to see the value as 0 in that time ID instead of not seeing any data.

Comment: Storing date values in a `char` column is a really, really bad idea to begin with

Answer (score 0):

Use `generate_series()` . . but with your value converted to a date.  Then use `left join`:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select d.name, d.dte, coalesce(t.hour, 0) as hour
from (select name, generate_series(mind, maxd, interval '1 day') dte
      from (select name, min(date_id)::text::date as mind, max(date_id)::text::date as maxd
            from t
            group by name
           ) t
     ) d left join
     t
     on d.name = t.name and
        d.dte = t.date_id::text::date
```